# Magento 2 - $product->save is not saving/updating data

Tags: magento2, magento2.1.5

I wanted to do simple price update script, that loads data from xml and passes it to product queried by custom attribute "ean".

I am able to get the product by 2 different ways ProductRepositoryInterface and ProductFactory, when i try to save product using interface i get error that "Class string not found..." when i try to save product by using ProductFactory (save method of product model) then nothing happens.

Using Magento 2.1.5

After long hours of googling and trying i have not seen other types of solutions to retrieve, edit and save product.

I have tried to re-index afterwards to delete cache... ) My code is test.php located in magento2 root directory

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

include('app/bootstrap.php');
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productInterface */
$productInterface = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');

/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $productModel */
$productModel = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory')->create();

$file = dirname(__FILE__) . "/Zasoby.xml";
$xml_content = file_get_contents($file);
$xml_content = str_replace(array("stk:", "lStk:", "rsp:", "typ:"), array("", "", "", ""), $xml_content);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_content);

# Quick switch between interface method and model method
$update_using_interface = false;

foreach ($xml->responsePackItem->listStock->stock as $item):

    $item = $item->stockHeader;

    if (!isset($item->EAN)):
        continue;
    endif;

    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
    $product = $productModel->loadByAttribute("ean", $item->EAN);

    if (!$product):
        continue;
    endif;

    # Product is found so lets start update
    echo "Updating product: " . $product->getName() . "<br/>";

    if ($update_using_interface):
        $product = $productInterface->getById($product->getId(), true);
    endif;

    # Update name and price
    $product->setName($item->name);
    $product->setPrice($item->sellingPrice);

    if ($update_using_interface):
        # Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class string does not exist'
        $productInterface->save($product);
    else:
        $product->save();
        $product->reindex();
    endif;

endforeach;
```

Thank you for any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem, $product->setName($item->name); vs $product->setName($item->name->__toString());

When working with simplexml, it returns object that has magic method __toString() which works fine in nearly any case, for example while loadnig product by attribute ->__toString was not required, it automatically detected. But when setting product data its required, otherwise magento will try to search class "String" instead of doing the __toString() magic.

Comment: what was the issue, we are not using toString anywhere in the code

Answer (score 0):

Doing something that would cast it to a string also does this for you.

E.g. trim the value.

```
$product
    ->setSku(trim($exportProduct->sku))
    ->setName(trim($exportProduct->name));
```